# Program downloads the file and instantly deletes it

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make a music bot for Discord but I am having a problem at the play section. The program successfully downloads the mp3 but instantly deletes it and I can't see the problem.

The code:

````
    if voice.is_playing(): 
        queuelist.append(title)
        await ctx.send(f"**{title}** sıraya alındı!")
    else:
        voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(f"{title}.mp3"), after= lambda e : check_queue())
        # lambda is a way to write anonymous functions
        voice.volume = 100
        await ctx.send(f"Playing: **{title}** :musical_note:")
        filestodelete.append(title)
    
    def check_queue():
        try:
            if queuelist[0] != None:
                voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(f"{queuelist[0]}.mp3"), after= lambda e : check_queue())
                filestodelete.append(queuelist[0])
                queuelist.pop(0)
        except IndexError:
            for file in filestodelete:
                os.remove(f"{file}.mp3")
            filestodelete.clear() ```
````

Comment: what is your error message

Comment: As an example, when I put a song link with that title it gives me this OS Error, and the weird thing is this time it did not delete it, instead it just didn't play it.    
   
Error:
      
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: ' Asereje (The Ketchup song) - LasKetChup | Just Dance 4  .mp3'

Comment: I recommend that you debug your code, maybe your check_queue except doesn't work as intended.